# How to use str to convert an exception object to string using str in Python?

Tags: python, exception

I have seen code which 'converts' exception objects to the error string using str() like this:

```
try:
  ...
except Exception, err:
  print str(err)
```

Does err contain some public 'interface' through which its error string is fetched?
I want to have the same functionality for my custom exception class. One way i can think of doing is just define a global str() method for all my exception objects and then inside just return the error string using getter. Is that how I should do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just define [`__str__`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__) method for your exception class.